# Update display in using python and tkinter; do I need to create an event to enable mainroot to run?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

This is my first post, so please bear with me.  I have a discrete event simulation that runs in simulated time, and as it steps through sim_time it updates a UI using the .grid geometry manager. It wants to make several updates without user-events like mouse clicks. I have tried using root.update_idletasks() and root.update() - they work to a degree, but it is still choppy and lingers without a clean refresh. If I implement it so that you have to click a button for each sim_time tick, then it waits in mainroot() for the user input, and all is clean. But for me to make multiple updates programmatically causes it to burp in the refresh.

I am thinking about creating a timer that runs in a separate process and pulses the simulation to advance a tick but that seems complex and I imagine there is a simpler answer.

Here is an example of objects being placed in a frame. I might do many of these based on what is flowing through the process being simulated.

```
def add(self, opp):
    """ add an opp to a display frame """
    self.opps.append(opp)
    b=Button(self.f, image=opp.icon, command=lambda: self.bp_opp(opp))
    opp.button = b
    #
    #
    # note there is probably a way to get the geometry manager to do this
    #
    r = (len(self.opps) -1) // self.max_opps_per_row 
    c = (len(self.opps) - 1)  % self.max_opps_per_row
    self.o.grid()
    self.f.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    if c <= self.max_opps_per_row:
        b.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky=W)
    return()
```

In the above, o is a parent frame that contains frame f, and there are several buttons b that are placed in f.
In the visual representation the buttons flow from one part of the process to another and ideally one could pause the simulation and query the process by pressing the buttons.
So after several layers of a process do their versions of the above, the control passes to a master ticker and it does this:

```
        my_ui.root.update_idletasks()
        my_ui.root.after(100)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Now if this were strictly user event driven, I would just have it come back to root.mainloop() and wait for the next mouse click or whatever, but I am simulating time and I want to increment time and to another cycle, so the root.update_idletasks() is supposed to update all the grid() manipulation.

I have tried moving the grid statements around, and reordered them to be absolutely sure they are in the order of the layering of the frames and buttons, and I have tried various forms of root.update() and root.update_idletasks(). Some work better than others, but none seem to do the trick. I am thinking that I should just create a periodic event that wakes up my simulation timer that will ultimately return to root.mainloop()

Comment: first of it would be great if You could provide [mre], otherwise about the timer, You could use `.after()` method, more info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/) or just try looking up on google

Comment: Have you tried using `.after` scripts? Also how long does it take to run a step of the simulation?

Comment: OK I added what I hope is a more complete explanation

Comment: @cgaar You shouldn't have `time.sleep` in your tkinter functions. Also you aren't using `.after` correctly.

Comment: I took it out. It was there for me to slow it down so I could see if it would refresh. I have rewritten the timer and forced it to wait for a buttonclick for each tick of the timer clock, and I have put a update_idletasks() and .after() calls in there. I am actually destroying buttons and recreating them in latter stages of the process, so I am actually moving buttons from place to place in different frames. Maybe that is too high overhead.